# Method not writing to file

Tags: c, file, printf, writetofile

I am trying to create a method in C so I can write to a file but I am not sure why it's not working. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
void writeToFile(Employee *employeeRecords, int count) {

    FILE * f = NULL;
    fopen("employeeData.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *text = "Employee data: \n";
    fputs(text, f);

    for(int l = 0; l < count; l++) {

        fprintf(f, "%c", employeeRecords[l].name);      
        fprintf(f, "%c", employeeRecords[l].surname);
        fprintf(f, "%d", employeeRecords[l].age);
        fprintf(f, "%lf", employeeRecords[l].salary);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" - what exactly? Does opening the file fail? Is anything written to the file, but not what you expected?

Comment: It does not give any errors but also does not write anything on the file

Comment: The code you've posted should always print "Error opening file!", because you never assign the result of `fopen`.

Comment: Do you run the program from some IDE where the terminal window is closed immediately and you simply don't see the error message(s)?

Comment: No, but I am not sure why it did not. Anyway, thank you a lot for the suggestion. I hadn't noticed it was missing. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
f=fopen("employeeData.txt", "w");
```

Comment: Yes, this was it. I hadn't noticed. Thank you